# Display CFG from llvm in xvcg

Tags: llvm, control-flow-graph, vcg, xvcg

There is `-view-cfg` option ([doc](http://llvm.org/docs/Passes.html#view-cfg-view-cfg-of-function)) in llvm's `opt` program, which enables me to view the Control Flow Graph via `dot` program. But the CFG in too big to be rendered as postscript from dot. I know that there is the [`xvcg` utiity](http://directory.fsf.org/wiki/Xvcg) capable of displaying complex graphs, including CFG (and its [man](http://pwet.fr/man/linux/commandes/xvcg) says "VCG tool - visualization of compiler graphs").

So, how can I output llvm's CFG in xvcg format?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Directly generating .vcg files from LLVM will require heavy modifications to [GraphWriter](http://llvm.org/docs/doxygen/html/classllvm_1_1GraphWriter.html), which is very GraphViz-specific. Instead, it seems to me that the most straightforward solution will be to save a dot file (via `-dot-cfg` instead of `-view-cfg`) and then convert it, using something like [Graph-Easy](http://search.cpan.org/~tels/Graph-Easy/bin/graph-easy). From its documentation (emphasis mine):

> It understands the following formats as input:
>
> - Graph::Easy  http://bloodgate.com/perl/graph/manual/
> - **DOT          http://www.graphviz.org/**
> - VCG          http://rw4.cs.uni-sb.de/~sander/html/gsvcg1.html
> - GDL          http://www.aisee.com/
>
> The output can be a dump of the graph in one of the following formats:
>
> - Graph::Easy  http://bloodgate.com/perl/graph/manual/
> - DOT          http://www.graphviz.org/
> - **VCG          http://rw4.cs.uni-sb.de/~sander/html/gsvcg1.html**
> - GDL          http://www.aisee.com/
> - GraphML      http://graphml.graphdrawing.org/

By the way, if you want to get a lot of graphs and prefer to see them before generating a lot of dot files, consider using a dot viewer which also allows you to save the file, such as [my fork of xdot.py](https://github.com/amishne/xdot.py) - or better yet, modify `xdot.py` so that it knows how to save in .vcg format itself, using Graph-Easy.

Another alternative to Graph-Easy appears to be [dot2gdl](http://dot2gdl.sourceforge.net/).

Comment: Thanks! There is a feature of xvcg when working with large CFGs - you can interactively open some nodes to see contents of basic blocks, by default all blocks are collapsed. Is there such feature in xdot or in Graph-Easy?

Comment: @osgx that does sound useful. Graphviz itself has no such functionality, and xdot.py is actually a viewer for xdot files which are already after the layout stage, so it cannot help. I guess it's possible to write a viewer which will allow this by dynamically removing some of the nodes/edges and then use dot layout again, but I know of no such viewer. Maybe it's worth asking in a separate question, though...

Comment: Oak, the changing (rewrawing) of the graph may be not needed, even ability to draw graph in collapsed variant and per-node content viewing (as separate floating windows) will be great. PS there is another converter to vcg from dot ...

Comment: @osgx well, I guess you could massage any existing viewer to do that - xdot.py is particularly convenient because it's pure python and is already somewhat interactive - but I don't know of any viewer with such a built-in functionality.

Comment: Oak, xvcg is. Another converter to vcg from dot is dot2gdl.

Comment: @osgx I agree, if you need this functionality then stick with your viewer and just convert the dot files to vcg.

Comment: @osgx thanks, edited it into the answer for future reference.